# How to sum elements of nested list in Autolisp?

Tags: lisp, autolisp

I am beginning to code in LISP, so I don't know much.
I have a list of coordinates, and I want to add each x and y for each point and put them into a new variable.
the list:
`((587243.0 4.04705e+006) (587242.0 4.04704e+006) (587228.0 4.04704e+006)  (587226.0 4.04704e+006) (587227.0 4.04705e+006) (587243.0 4.04705e+006))`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So expected result is one single numer: summ of all summ like, 587243.0+4.04705e+006+587242.0+4.04704e+006 ....

Comment: no I expect to get a list of each element sums, lik ((587242.0+4.04704e+006) (587228.0+4.04704e+006) etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `mapcar` & `apply` for this task, e.g.:

```lisp
(setq lst
   '(
        (587243.0 4.04705e+006)
        (587242.0 4.04704e+006)
        (587228.0 4.04704e+006)
        (587226.0 4.04704e+006)
        (587227.0 4.04705e+006)
        (587243.0 4.04705e+006)
    )
)
(mapcar '(lambda ( x ) (apply '+ x)) lst)
```

```lisp
(4.63429e+06 4.63428e+06 4.63427e+06 4.63427e+06 4.63428e+06 4.63429e+06)
```